# ubuntu 20.10 wifi connected but no internet connection. how to solve this

Tags: networking, package-management, 20.04, internet, ubuntu-drivers

I have tried all suggestions given in forums like editing resolv.conf, gaif.conf etc.
I think the system is not able to properly compile rtl8723de driver.
The kernel version is 5.8.0-29-generic.
the wifi was working well with version 19.10 . but after upgrade to 20.04 LTS the problem started. And i tried all suggested commands but did not succeed. Hence, upgraded to 20.10 thinking the problem could have been sorted out there. But a big NO..

can somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a driver for this adapter. Connect to the internet by other means and run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88.git
sudo dkms add ./rtw88
sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
```

Comment: Thanks,  the adaptor rtl8723de is already installed and wifi is connected. But websites are not getting connected